# Return DB query results in table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This script works below to return the number of current user's "movies". But I want to go further and have the page display all of the movie names "movie_names" and genres "genre" in a table. I have tried a bunch of things, but having some trouble doing this in wordpress.

```
<?php 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
?>
Movies: <?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(*) as total from movies where ID = $user_ID");
print "<a href=\"http://example.com/active\">" .$results[0]->total ."</a><br>";

?>
```

Comment: I can prob make this work with mysqli but then I need to get the db connection info and such. I want to use the wordpress global $wpdb so it's less code and cleaner and the recommended way in wp. But I don't know how to this in wp

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from movies where ID = $user_ID");
print_r ($results);

$numberOfMovies = count($results);;
while($count < $numberOfMovies)
{
    print "{$results[$count]->movie_names}";
    print "{$results[$count]->genres}";
    $count = $count + 1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This works well. Howlin, just saw your post as I came here to type my successful code and so haven't tried yours. But it might help someone else. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;


$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM movies where ID = $user_ID");
if ($results) {
echo '<table>';
foreach ($results as $row) {
// Each $row is a row from the query
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row->movie_name; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->genre; '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```